# Web.config Active Directory Groups IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

I'm having an issue where most users are able to access my application, but a few aren't. The message these users get is "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials".

In my web config, I have granted access to an all employees group that has everyone.

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Domain\ALLEMP" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I can't think of any good reason why this would be happening. Is there a workaround in IIS I can perform?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with sql server?

Comment: I didn't post code for it but I'm using SSO ID's in AD to authenticate users in a SQL Database in addition to this as an authentication method.